# How to create a column based on grouped condition?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My test tabe in powerbi:

| IdRecord | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-25 23:45:00.000 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-04-24 18:07:00.000 | 344 |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 23:45:00.000 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-05-02 18:07:00.000 | 66 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 18:07:00.000 | 31 |

I require to create a calculated column to mark the earliest of the records grouped by id.

Desired output

| IdRecord | Date | Value | IsFirst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-25 23:45:00.000 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-04-24 18:07:00.000 | 344 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 23:45:00.000 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-02 18:07:00.000 | 66 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 18:07:00.000 | 31 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself

```
FirstRes= VAR MYMIN =  CALCULATE(
MIN(Table[Date]),
FILTER ( Table, Table[IdRecord] = EARLIER(Table[IdRecord]))
)
RETURN   
IF(CALCULATE(
    MIN(MIN(Table[Date]),MYMIN),
    FILTER ( Table, Table[IdRecord] = EARLIER ( Table[IdRecord] ) )
) = Table[Date],1,0)
```